# <ClassName> extends non-API type <SuperclassName>

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I get this warning

```
[ClassName] extends non-API type [SuperclassName]
```

The package superclass sits is visible, and the warning goes on. What does this mean, and how do we prevent this?

Comment: Perhaps add an example? What class are you extending?

Comment: Are you extending a class that is not native to java, and that you have no source for?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug that is still not fixed in 2019-06. I use a usage problem filter to get rid of the warning.

Edit: If your interfaces are @ProviderType, adding @noimplement to both interfaces javadoc solves the issue.